# How to get into a vob on rcleartool

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

I have type the **`lsvob`** command in `rcleartool` and it is giving me the list of vob's.

Now how to get into a particular vob?
I am trying `cd /clinical` but getting error:

```
CRCLI2027E Unable to change directory to "/clinical": No such directory.
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using CCRC (the ClearCase Remote Client), in order to access files in a VOB, you must

1. Create an automatic view or a Web view using the ClearTeam Explorer (CTE) GUI or 'rcleartool mkview ...' from the command line.
2. If you're using an automatic view, mount the VOB using CTE or 'rcleartool mount ...'.  If you're using a Web view, add a load rule to the view's configuration using CTE (i.e. add "/clinical" in the "Load Rules" tab - accessible from the "Show ClearCase View Configuration" menu item on the context menu for the view)  or 'rcleartool edcs' (i.e. add a line "load /clinical" to the configuration specification).

Then go to the view root directory (R:\<view_tag>\ for an automatic view or the path to the copyarea for a Web view) and the VOB tag should be visible in that directory.  You can 'cd' into the VOB from that context.

For more details the man pages for the commands are at:

[mkview](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkview.htm)

[mount](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mount.htm)

[edcs](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_edcs.htm)

Comment: I got into the vob and lshistory command is working now how to run the annotate command

Comment: **rcleartool> annotate**   this command is giving error
_CRCLI2002E Unrecognized command: "annotate"_.

Comment: 'rcleartool' is a work in progress and is being enhanced over time.  The "Applicability" section at the top of the command's man page indicates whether the command is supported in 'rcleartool'.  As the [annotate][1] man page indicates, it is only (currently) available from 'cleartool'.

[1]: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_annotate.htm

Answer (score 0):

`/clinical` is not a path, it is a **vob tag**.
See "[VOB tags and VOB access](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/c_rgy_data_tags_access_vob.htm?lang=en)".

To access it contents, you need either:

- a snapshot or ccweb view, with a load rule for that vob

  ```
  LOAD /clinical
  ```

(See more at "[ClearCase view configuration](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/c_ccview_config.htm?lang=en)" and "[View or edit load rules](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/u_ccview_config_loadrulestab.htm?lang=en)")

- or a dynamic view, with that **[vob mounted](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/t_mount_vob.htm?lang=en)** beforehand ([`rcleartool mount`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mount.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-2-3-2&lang=en))

  ```
  rcleartool mount /clinical
  ```

(then [start the dynamic view](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/t_start_dynamic_view.htm?lang=en))